# How can I add page size A0 to Microsoft XPS Document Writer?

Tags: c#, excel

in my c#-code is written:

```
excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) +
"\\" + output)
```

It makes a pdf-file in A4, not in A0. I had to add page size A0 to Microsoft XPS Document Writer manually, but how does it work in c#?

A4 means 210 × 297 mm
A0 means 841 × 1189 mm

Comment: I think you have to set this at the worksheet level see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pagesetup.papersize.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Macros are your friend here. Depending in the Excel version you use, first format the source document visually with the correct print settings while recording a new macro. Look at the generated VBA to get an idea about which PrintSettings properties to set.

The export manually using Excel to make sure it adds your required A0 size. If it does, then simply port the VBA code to your C# app.

**EDIT:**

Manually setting print properties in Excel involves things like setting page orientation, print margins, paper sizes, etc. If you do come across an object that you cannot reach in the Excel Object Model, you could always use a pre-formatted template in C#. Open the template, add your data, then export.

Recording macros is an extremely powerful way to quickly discover the Office Object Model. In the newer versions of Excel, I believe you need to enable the developer toolbar explicitly by `File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Developer Checkbox`.